# Javascript Image object re-using reference variable, cancels request?

Tags: javascript, image, object

Tricky getting the title right on this one.

If I use Javascript image object to track something, the http request is done asynchronously (it's not a blocking call), so I've always been concerned that if I re-use the variable that's a reference to the image object, I might be forcing the request to be cancelled. Here's some code that might illustrate my concern.

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = URL1;  //hit server with request 1
img = new Image(); //re-use the img variable for the next new Image
img.src = URL2;  //and now request 2. Would this cancel request 1 ?
```

I can (and currently do) work around this potential problem by having an array of Image objects and I take the next available one, and wrap around at 10. Something **like** this:

```
var imgs=[], index=0;
function send(url) {
    imgs[index] = new Image();
    imgs[index++].src = url;
    if(index>=10)index=0; //wraparound
}
send(URL1);
send(URL2);
```

I know that when re-using the img object in that first code example, I'm not actually doing anything to that original image object, I'm simply orphaning it - reducing it's refcount to zero and opening it up for garbage collection.

Would I be likely to find (in the first example) that the first request was cancelled/aborted? Or would it always complete, only to find that on completion nobody's interested?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the correct way. If you want to find out whether your request has been cancel or not, install Firebug for your firefox then open net request tab and observe

Comment: Thanks for that answer. Unfortunately that only answers the question for one browser. I'm hoping for a definitive answer across all browsers. Something like "the requests are never aborted" :-)